# Редирект страницы с кодом 40x

Tags: php, redirect, http-status-code-404, поисковые-системы

Скорее всего не знаю спецификацию, или суть происходящего.
Решил сделать редирект с кодом 404:

```
header("Location: /redirect/url",TRUE,404);
```

Редирект не произошел, сделал так (1):

```
http_response_code(404);
header("Location: /redirect/url",TRUE,303);
```

И вот чую, что перебздел, тогда есть такой вариант (2):

```
http_response_code(404);
header("Location: /redirect/url",TRUE);
```

Или такой (3):

```
header("Location: /redirect/url",TRUE,303);
```

Нужно что бы страницы не попала в индекс, а реальный пользователь был перенаправлен на главную.

Какой из вариантов (1,2,3) верный и что в итоге увидят поисковики, что страницы нет с кодом 404 и потом смотреть тут с 303 (это про вариант 1)?

Comment: Если у вас ссылок много, не стоит ставить всем 404 т.к это негативно повлияет на рейтинг у ботов. Если ссылки уже не активны, лучше поставить код 301 Moved Permanently («перемещено навсегда»). Через некоторое время пауки забудут об этих ссылках ))

Comment: Если последовать совету @borodatych, ботам будет хорошо, людям - плохо. Кейс: человек щелкает по ссылке, ожидает определенное содержимое, но его кидает на главную. Задайте себе вопрос - это ожидаемое поведение от сайта?